# What authorization do I need to fly a rebuilt aircraft that doesn't have an airworthiness certificate yet?

Tags: faa-regulations

Let's say I rebuild an aircraft in the USA and it does not have a current airworthiness certificate. The DAR requests a check flight during the process of issuing the new airworthiness certificate.

My question is: do I need a check flight authorization or permit from the FSDO to be able to fly without an airworthiness certificate?

Comment: Welcome to Aviation.se! I assume since you mention FISDO's that you are asking about American regulations. You should add that to your question as answer may vary by jurisdiction.